# Where are test instrumentation crash messages written?

Tags: android, android-studio

Running android tests with Android Studio, anyone know where trace files such the one below are to be found? This is on the device I guess?

```
Test instrumentation process crashed.  Check uk.co.xxx.tm.DnDTest#start_NoDndPerm.txt for details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is from the test orchestrator. It stores these files on the device. Check here: `/data/data/android.support.test.orchestrator/files/`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting permission denied on my Nexus 5X though:  

`bullhead:/ $ cd data
bullhead:/data $ ls
ls: .: Permission denied`

Comment: Your device has to be rooted in order to gain full access the `/data/` directory, inconveniently enough.